# Pylint: __init__ [abstract-method] vs [useless-super-delegation] warning

Tags: python, pylint, delegation, static-classes, abstract-methods

I have a problem where I must chose between two warnings:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbstractBaseClass:

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("The AbstractBaseClass class is designed to be used in a static way.")

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def is_valid():
        pass

class UselessSuperDelegation(AbstractBaseClass):

    # Useless super delegation in method '__init__' (18:4) [useless-super-delegation]
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(UselessSuperDelegation, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def is_valid():
        return True

class AbstratInitNotImplemented(AbstractBaseClass):

    # Method '__init__' is abstract in class 'AbstractBaseClass' but is not overrideden (25:0) [abstract-method]
    @staticmethod
    def is_valid():
        return True
```

The production class absolutely needs to be static and cannot even be used as a singleton, so it is really important the constructor throw an exception. From this point, I cannot avoid having one of the other warning. Maybe there's another approach ?

If not, which warning would you keep (and disable) ?

Comment: If `AbstractBaseClass` has a method decorated as abstract, you don't need to do anything. The metaclass already prevents you from instantiating it directly.

Comment: Also, are you really using Python 2? (Python 3 doesn't use the class attribute `__metaclass__`; it uses a keyword argument `metaclass` in the list of base classes instead.)

Comment: If you mean the *subclasses* need to remain abstract, why are you defining classes in the first place? Otherwise, I would just define a second private method as abstract and leave it undocumented. Overriding the "abstractness" of an ABC is trivial anyway, so don't expect it to be a bulletproof way of preventing instantiation.

Comment: The child classes shall not be instantiated either so it is necessary to disable the constructor. Yes we are using Python 2. The subclasses are not abstract they are static and should be used that way only. I do not care if someone simply workaround basic POO concepts he is responsible for his failures.

Comment: What do you mean by "static class"? I'm really not seeing why you have classes at all.

Comment: A static class is a class that cannot be instantiated.
And I need classes, that's all. So is there a way to get rid of those warnings ?

Comment: What's wrong with a module full of regular functions? You are using classes for something they aren't intended for.

Comment: Thank you but what I need is a solution for my issue, not a rework proposal.
If there's none, I'll deal with it.